# Customize sections in table of contents using title format

Tags: titlesec

I want to enumerate correctly the sections in the table of contents using `\titleformat`. I used the code below, but the numbers of sections aren't correct as shown in the attached image!

Thank you for helping me if you can.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\titlebar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3cm] {
    \fill [cyan!25] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,2.5ex);
    \node [
        fill=cyan!60!white,
        anchor= base east,
        rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (3cm,0) {
        \textbf{\arabic{chapter}}
    };
}%
}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\large}{\titlebar}{0.1cm}{}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcommand\titlebaree{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3cm] {
    \fill [cyan!25] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,2.5ex);
    \node [
        fill=green!60!white,
        anchor= base east,
        rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (3cm,0) {
        \textbf{\arabic{chapter}.\thesection}
    };
}%
}
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\titlebaree}{0.1cm}{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\newcommand\titlebare{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3cm] {
    \fill [cyan!25] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,2.5ex);
    \node [
        fill=red!60!white,
        anchor= base east,
        rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (3cm,0) {
        \textbf{\arabic{subsection}.\thesubsection}
    };
}%
}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large}{\titlebare}{0.1cm}{}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section One}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\section{Section name}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection One}
\lipsum[1]



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't understand what you're trying to obtain. You wrote no code for the table of contents layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not redefine `\thesection` and use `\thesection` and `\thesubsection` in `\titlebaree` and `\titlebare` respectively:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\titlebar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3cm] {
    \fill [cyan!25] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,2.5ex);
    \node [
        fill=cyan!60!white,
        anchor= base east,
        rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (3cm,0) {
        \textbf{\arabic{chapter}}
    };
}%
}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\large}{\titlebar}{0.1cm}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcommand\titlebaree{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3cm] {
    \fill [cyan!25] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,2.5ex);
    \node [
        fill=green!60!white,
        anchor= base east,
        rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (3cm,0) {
        \textbf{\thesection}% <- changed
    };
}%
}
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\titlebaree}{0.1cm}{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}% <- removed

\newcommand\titlebare{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3cm] {
    \fill [cyan!25] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,2.5ex);
    \node [
        fill=red!60!white,
        anchor= base east,
        rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (3cm,0) {
        \textbf{\thesubsection}% <- changed
    };
}%
}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large}{\titlebare}{0.1cm}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section One}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection One}
\section{Section name}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection One}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection Three}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]